# Isotopic classes of Jordan arcs on circle $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, curves

Consider Jordan arcs on one-dimensional circle, i.e. continuous and injective maps $\varphi: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{S}^1$.

We will say that $\varphi \simeq \psi$ if there is a homeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{S}^1$ such that $f$ is isotopic to identity, $(f\circ\varphi)([0, 1]) = \psi([0, 1])$ and $(f \circ \varphi)(0) = \psi(0)$, i.e. homeomorphism which maps one arc to another preserving starting points. Clearly it is an equivalence relation.

I would like to prove that there are exactly two equivalence classes of $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{S}^1)/\simeq$.

The idea is that all arcs "going in the same direction with respect to starting points" are equivalent, and "going in different directions" are not. Thus, we have exactly two possibilities for any class (clockwise or counterclockwise direction), which finishes the proof. Nevertheless, I do not know how to write a precise proof of this idea.

Comment: Don't you want to work with the set of Jordan Arcs modulo equivalence, not the set of homeomorphisms of $S^1$? Additionally, here's a possible outline: first note that you can assume all your arcs begin at the same point by suitably rotating any arc which doesn't begin at that point, as a rotation will not change the equivalence class. Next, observe that the image of a Jordan arc is determined by the start and end points together with a direction vector at the start point, as a continuous and injective map from $I$. Finally, compose with an appropriate homeomorphism based on the direction

Comment: vector to make all counterclockwise JAs equivalent to one specific one (say, a semicircle), and do the same with clockwise arcs.

Comment: Of course, it then remains to prove that those two chosen arcs are not equivalent, but you can probably do this by hand, perhaps proving that the tangent vector associated to the image of a jordan curve is appropriately invariant under isotopy.

Comment: Do you know what a covering projection is? In this case $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$?

Comment: I think you do not mean equivalence classes of **homeomorphisms** as  $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{S}^1)/\simeq$ suggests.  If $\mathscr{JA}(S^1)$ notes the set of Jordan arcs in $S^1$, you mean $\mathscr{JA}(S^1)/\simeq$.